# Pattern Matching using a keyword list from another list and remapping to a subsequent category if matched else Category as blank

Tags: python

Here is code :

```py
Matched =np.array([False]*NewAGs.shape[0])
NewAGs["Tower"] = np.nan

for rowNum in range(Keywords.shape[0]):

    ## Get the keyword in the current row.
    keyword = Keywords.lowerKeywords[rowNum]
    ## Get Assignment groups with the keyword:
    index = (re.search("^" + keyword + "[^w+]", NewAGs.lowerAG[0]) or
    re.search("[^w+]"+keyword+"[^w+]", NewAGs.lowerAG[0]) or
    re.search("[^w+]"+keyword+"$", NewAGs.lowerAG[0]) or
    re.search("^"+keyword+"$", NewAGs.lowerAG[0]))
    print(bool(index))
    ## Select Only the Unmatched Assignment groups:

    index = index and index != -1
    print(sum(index))

    if index != 0
    NewAGs['Tower'[index]] <- Keywords['Tower'[rowNum]]
    Matched <- Matched or index
```

Comment: This question is very vague. Please specify what exactly you are tryng to accomplish and what you want

Comment: lets say there are 3 columns 1 AssignedGroup - Infra Global 2. Keyword - Infra Category - Infrastructure. i want to find the keyword from AssignedGroup and map it to a category defined based on the keyword which is the third column.